# Why is the initialization value of derived class member not lost when it's converted to a base pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism

In the following code I was expecting the value of the `b` member of class `B` to be lost since I assigned it to a base pointer `A` which doesn't have any member `b`. But it seems to be stored somewhere and I still get the correct value of 30 in last line.

I didn't expect this. Can someone explain how this is managed in memory?

Does it mean that when we are allocating the derived class members all the members are there in memory, and their accessibility depends on whether or not a base class pointer is used to access that member or not?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(): a(5) {}
    A(int val): a(val) {}
    int a;
    virtual void f() {}
};

class B: public A {
public:
    B(): a(5), b(10) {}
    B(int val1, int val2): a(val1), b(val2) {}
    int a;
    int b;
    virtual void f() {
        cout<<"Dummy";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A *a = new B(20, 30);
    cout<<"a->a: "<<a->a<<endl;
    B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    cout<<"b->a: "<<b->a<<" | b->b: "<<b->b;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
a->a: 5
b->a: 20 | b->b: 30
```

Comment: Do you know what inheritance is and how it works?

Comment: Yes I do. I wanted to know how runtime polymorhism occurs inside C++ and was under a (false) assumption that if runtime created derived class object is cast to base class object then the extra field of derived class object should be unallocated as base class doesn't need it. Moreover if you cast this back to dynamic then the new members would be again created. Seems like this doesn't happen and the extra fields will always be there occupying memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not lost, because the object is still of the type `B`. The extra `a` you add in `B` is an entirely different member than the `a` in `A`, and the `b` member follows it. The pointer just points at the `A` sub-object of the complete `B` object you created. Conceptually, it looks something like this:

```
    +--------------------+
    +------+      |      |
a-->| A::a | B::a | B::b |
    +------+      |      |
    +--------------------+
```

You see the value `5` printed because your c'tor:

```
B(int val1, int val2): a(val1), b(val2) {}
```

Doesn't specify an initializer for the `A` base of `B`. So it's default initialized, and so the default c'tor (the one that set `A::a` to 5) is the one called.

`b->a` accesses the value of `B::a` because you indeed used a `B` pointer, and that affects how name lookup works.

Comment: Thanks! I was exactly looking for the a --> | ... diagram that you provided. Gives the apt insight I needed. Thanks again!